# Hovertemplate not working for Plotly Surface plots

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python, surface

I stumbled upon a problem with plotly hovertemplates where the text is created differently for surface plots and other kinds of plots, for example heatmaps. For surface plots the hovertemplate completely fails

While for heatmaps the hovertemplate can be fed from the customdata variable perfectly fine like it is done in the documentation:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.offline import plot as htmly

x = np.round(np.arange(-5,5,0.2),2)
y = np.round(np.arange(0,5,0.2),2)
z = np.matrix([[x[i]**2 + (y[j] - 2.5)**2 for i in range(len(x))] for j in range(len(y))])
mesh = np.meshgrid(x,y)
customdata_ = np.dstack((mesh[0], mesh[1]))

fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Heatmap(
    z=z, customdata=customdata_,
    hovertemplate='<b>z:%{z:.3f}</b><br>x:%{customdata[0]:.3f} <br>y: %{customdata[1]:.3f} '))
fig.update_layout(
    xaxis=dict(title='x', tickmode='array', ticktext=x, tickvals=np.arange(len(x))),
    yaxis=dict(title='y', tickmode='array', ticktext=y, tickvals=np.arange(len(y))),
    font=dict(size=14)
)
htmly(fig)
```

The same **does not work** for surface plots:

```
fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Surface(
    z=z, customdata=customdata_,
    hovertemplate='<b>z:%{z:.3f}</b><br>x:%{customdata[0]:.3f} <br>y: %{customdata[1]:.3f} '))
fig.update_layout(
    scene=dict(
        xaxis=dict(title='x', tickmode='array', ticktext=x, tickvals=np.arange(len(x))),
        yaxis=dict(title='y', tickmode='array', ticktext=y, tickvals=np.arange(len(y)))
    ),
    font=dict(size=14)
)
htmly(fig)
```

For surface plots only a limited set of data points shows the hovertemplate (with false values). For the rest the hovertemplate is just interpreted as a literal string.
[image]

Has somebody managed to create a correct hovertext from the hovertemplate field in a similar way?

Comment: From what has been posted in the [plolty community](https://community.plotly.com/t/setting-custom-tooltip-on-3d-surface-plot/59690), it appears that custom data for surfaces is not working at this time. I tried hover data and hover templates as a possibility in this comment, but it did not work.